# xaml Cannot align text vertically in in DataGrid template

Tags: wpf, text, datagrid, cell, vertical-alignment

I'm trying to align text within all cells of a DataGrid to center. All examples I've found on how to do thi shows smaller DataGrids where there is a ContentPresenter which has the property to align text vertically, how ever my Style for DataGrid doesn't have ContentPresenter. I've tried to align through creating a

```
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
```

in the Style with TargetType x:Type DataGrid.

The entire code of the Style looks like this

```
<Style x:Key="myDataGrid" TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}">
    <Setter Property="AlternatingRowBackground" Value="WhiteSmoke"/>
    <!-- <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}"/> -->
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource grayBackground}"/>
    <Setter Property="RowBackground" Value="{DynamicResource rowWhiteBackground}"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource standardRed}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Helvetica"/>
    <Setter Property="GridLinesVisibility" Value="Vertical"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalGridLinesBrush" Value="LightGray"/>
    <Setter Property="RowDetailsVisibilityMode" Value="VisibleWhenSelected"/>
    <Setter Property="MinRowHeight" Value="30"/>
    <Setter Property="MinColumnWidth" Value="100"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.PanningMode" Value="Both"/>
    <Setter Property="Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}">
                <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                    <ScrollViewer x:Name="DG_ScrollViewer" Focusable="false">
                        <ScrollViewer.Template>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <Button Command="{x:Static DataGrid.SelectAllCommand}" Focusable="false" Style="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=DataGridSelectAllButtonStyle, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type DataGrid}}}" Visibility="{Binding HeadersVisibility, ConverterParameter={x:Static DataGridHeadersVisibility.All}, Converter={x:Static DataGrid.HeadersVisibilityConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}" Width="{Binding CellsPanelHorizontalOffset, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"/>
                                    <DataGridColumnHeadersPresenter x:Name="PART_ColumnHeadersPresenter" Grid.Column="1" Visibility="{Binding HeadersVisibility, ConverterParameter={x:Static DataGridHeadersVisibility.Column}, Converter={x:Static DataGrid.HeadersVisibilityConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"/>
                                    <ScrollContentPresenter x:Name="PART_ScrollContentPresenter" CanContentScroll="{TemplateBinding CanContentScroll}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="1"/>
                                    <ScrollBar x:Name="PART_VerticalScrollBar" Grid.Column="2" Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableHeight}" Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Row="1" Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility}" Value="{Binding VerticalOffset, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportHeight}"/>
                                    <Grid Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2">
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding NonFrozenColumnsViewportHorizontalOffset, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ScrollBar x:Name="PART_HorizontalScrollBar" Grid.Column="1" Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableWidth}" Orientation="Horizontal" Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedHorizontalScrollBarVisibility}" Value="{Binding HorizontalOffset, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportWidth}"/>
                                    </Grid>
                                </Grid>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </ScrollViewer.Template>
                        <ItemsPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <MultiTrigger>
            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Property="IsGrouping" Value="true"/>
                <Condition Property="VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizingWhenGrouping" Value="false"/>
            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="false"/>
        </MultiTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

The code is taken from a copy of DataGrid style that I'm editing in Blend and Visual Studio. I cannot find where or how I could align the text of all cells vertically. Appreciate all help I can get.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
<DataGrid.LayoutTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <RotateTransform Angle="90" />
                    <MatrixTransform Matrix="-1,0,0,1,0,0" />
                </TransformGroup>
            </DataGrid.LayoutTransform>
            <DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}"
                        BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}}">
                    <Setter Property="LayoutTransform">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <TransformGroup>
                                <RotateTransform Angle="-90" />
                                <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1" ScaleY="-1" />
                            </TransformGroup>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
            <DataGrid.CellStyle>
                <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                    <Setter Property="LayoutTransform">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <TransformGroup>
                                <RotateTransform Angle="-90" />
                                <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1" ScaleY="-1" />
                            </TransformGroup>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.CellStyle>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do for you :

```
<Window.Resources>        
  <ControlTemplate x:Key="CustomCell" TargetType="DataGridCell">
      <Label HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Height="100">
          <ContentPresenter Width="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
      </Label>
  </ControlTemplate>       

   <Style TargetType="DataGridCell"> 
       <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource CustomCell}"/>
   </Style>

   ...

</Window.Resources>
```